# Testing ping and server availability swift

Tags: swift, server, ping

For example, there's a site named site.com. I need to check if the site can be loaded and test the ping to the server the site is on. Can you provide anything to read or an example of code. I just can't find anything related to this topic

Comment: You might consider [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html), which will tell you not only if the server is reachable, but will also asynchronously notify you if the status of the device's Internet connectivity changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an Objective-C library called `SimplePingHelper` from Chris Hulbert. It uses the Apple Code "[SimplePing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html)". You can find it on this [GitHub Page](https://github.com/chrishulbert/SimplePingHelper).

Just import the `.h` file into your Bridging-Header file:

```
#import "SimplePingHelper.h"
```

Then you can use the SimplePingHelper like shown [in the example](http://www.splinter.com.au/how-to-ping-a-server-in-objective-c-iphone/) on Chris' website. The code is written in Objective-c, but you can easily update it to Swift.

Comment: Thanks, but it only says if the host is reachable via ping, right? It doesn't actually return the average ping.